# Removing a black background to create a transparent image

Tags: inkscape

There is a way of removing the background in Inkscape using Bezier curves. For my project, this will be a lengthy task.

I have a white logo on a black background, I wish to have a white image of the logo on a transparent background. Is there a way to trace the white image using colour. There are only solutions for this with a white background, not a black one.

If this is possible, could you describe the process using Inkscape?

Comment: Is your problematic image a  vector (=bezier curves)  or a raster (PNG, JPG) image? Vectors should be possible to be recolored and some parts can be deleted or made transparent. PNGs and JPGs need different treatment. If you know how to do it when the background is white, why don't you invert the colors? For PNGs and JPGs it takes only few seconds in GIMP, Photoshop, Paint.NET or other bitmap editor.

Comment: Thanks for your response, it is a PNG, and I'll try to do do that

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible. I assume you have a black and white raster image, such as a JPEG or PNG.

1. Click *File > Import* to get the image into Inkscape.
2. Select the image, and click *Path > Trace Bitmap*
3. Use the settings shown below, making sure to check the option for "remove background".  If your logo is white on a black background, also select the "Invert image" option.

[image]

5. Change the fill colour of the resulting trace to any colour you want.